# How to pass data from a viewcontroller to a corresponding UICollectionView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm building a little iOS game in which a user can bid on a player inside a list of players in a collectionview.

In the third viewcontroller in the picture below, how can I make the bid appear in the collectionviewcell of the corresponding player?

[image: The three view controllers]

**1st view controller**

A vc with a UIcollectionview of players. The users selects a player here.

**2nd view controller**

In this destination vc the user sets a bid on the selected player.

Contains a slider:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureSlider()
}
```

Configured like this:

```
func configureSlider() {
    if let playerProfile = player {
        let minPrice = playerProfile.minPrice
        bidSliderLabel.value = Float(minPrice)
    }
}
```

A prepare for segue method sends the bid value to the third controller:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "bidResults") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! transferResultsViewController;

        svc.bidSet = "\(bidSliderLabel.value)"

    }
}
```

**3th view controller**

The bid set in vc 2 is stored in the bidSet variable:

```
var bidSet: String?
```

Now I want to add a UILabel to the collectionviewcell containing the bid:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bidSetLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bidSetLabel.text = bidSet
}
```

But this bidSetLabel should only be used for one collectionview cell: The one containing the player that received the bid.

How can I achieve this?

**Solution**

As suggested by Philip Mills in the comments, I ended up using a data model instead of segues. I stored the bid value inside the 2nd VC inside an instance which made it accessible to VC 3.

Comment: Are you maintaining a Player profile object in the `UICollectionViewCell` of the Third VC?

Comment: you should update your data source some how. One option is to add a `betValue` property on your player model object. Update that value on your second VC and on your third VC, when returning the collection cell check if that property is != 0 tho show the label.

Comment: Create an object that will manage your data.  Let it keep track of players, bids, and whatever else you need. Then, instead of creating dependencies between controllers, let them communicate with the data manager to get/update whatever they're supposed to display.

Comment: @UditS Yes because the third vc inherits from the first vc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Label to each collectionView cell. Give bidSetLabel `heightConstraint.constant=0` intially.

When you want to show bidSetLabel just pass index of that particular cell and set height to whatever you like for that particular cell.  `heightConstraint.constant=50` intially.

Or you can also Make `Player` Class which tracks the unique `player_uid` property if you have with the data you are showing in cell and set the height to `heightConstraint.constant=50` intially.